# SQL Convertion error in a Case When statement

Tags: sql-server, compiler-errors, null, type-conversion

I am trying to look at 4 date fields and select the most current one. Everything works great until I hit a field with nothing in it. Then I get a

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." error.

Is there a way to ignore the nulls ?

```
Select AP.ID, AP.CERT_DATE as 'Cert Date', AP.Recert_Date as 'Recert Date', AP.Recert_Date2 as 'Recert Date 2', AP.Recert_Date3 as 'Recert Date 3',
CASE    
    When AP.CERT_DATE > AP.Recert_Date AND AP.CERT_DATE > AP.Recert_Date2 AND AP.CERT_DATE > AP.Recert_Date3 Then AP.CERT_DATE
    When AP.Recert_Date > AP.CERT_DATE AND AP.Recert_Date > AP.Recert_Date2 AND AP.Recert_Date > AP.Recert_Date3 Then AP.Recert_Date
    When AP.Recert_Date2 > AP.CERT_DATE AND AP.Recert_Date2 > AP.Recert_Date AND AP.Recert_Date2 > AP.Recert_Date3 Then AP.Recert_Date2
    When AP.Recert_Date3 > AP.CERT_DATE AND AP.Recert_Date3 > AP.Recert_Date AND AP.Recert_Date3 > AP.Recert_Date2 Then AP.Recert_Date3
    ELSE 'Attention'
END AS 'Most Recent Year'
FROM Profile AP
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, a more developer friendly approach is to use [TRY_CONVERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703028/sql-convertion-error-in-a-case-when-statement), that allows to check whether a (n)varchar represents a valid date time of a specific format.

Applying Javier's answer, you can have something like this:

```
declare @minDate DATE = '19000101'

(SELECT Max(d) FROM (VALUES 
    (ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, CERT_DATE), @minDate), 
    (Recert_Date), 
    (Recert_Date2), 
    (Recert_Date3)
) AS value(d)) as 'Most Recent Year'
```

(apply `TRY_CONVERT` for varchars only)

However, if possible, try to have all dates columns to be of type `DATE` or `DATETIME2`, not `VARCHAR`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MSSQL 2008 or later, could you try this?

```
SELECT AP.ID, AP.CERT_DATE as 'Cert Date', AP.Recert_Date as 'Recert Date', AP.Recert_Date2 as 'Recert Date 2', AP.Recert_Date3 as 'Recert Date 3',
  (SELECT Max(d) 
   FROM (VALUES (CERT_DATE), (Recert_Date), (Recert_Date2), (Recert_Date3)) AS value(d)) as 'Most Recent Year'
FROM Profile AP
```

Btw, about your error, all the fields in the `when` statements are of type `date` and the field `else` statement is a `varchar`. You can't combine different types in an case structure. You should change the `else` field to a default date instead of a string, or, cast all fields in the `when` statements as `varchar`.

IMHO your query is hard to read and poorly maintanable, so I would suggest to use the alternative query I put above.

Edit: If you want to further process that new column you could do something like this (Alexei's example is much cleaner):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.CERT_DATE as 'Cert Date', A.Recert_Date as 'Recert Date', A.Recert_Date2 as 'Recert Date 2', A.Recert_Date3 as 'Recert Date 3'
, ISNULL(CAST(MaxDate as varchar),'Attention') -- I would prefer following Alexei's approach by declaring previously a mindate variable and do:  ISNULL(MaxDate, @MinDate) -- That way you can keep the date type output
, DATEDIFF (YY, MaxDate, GETDATE())
, Case When DATEADD (YY, DateDiff (YY, MaxDate, GETDATE()), MaxDate) > GETDATE () Then 1 Else 0 End
FROM 
(
SELECT AP.ID, AP.CERT_DATE, AP.Recert_Date, AP.Recert_Date2, AP.Recert_Date3
      (SELECT Max(d) 
       FROM (VALUES (CERT_DATE), (Recert_Date), (Recert_Date2), (Recert_Date3)) AS value(d)) as 'MaxDate'
    FROM Profile AP
) A
```

At the end of the day you will always be in the same place. You cannot combine varchar and date type on the same column. That's why you will need to cast one or another to the other type.
Applying to Alexei's recommendation you could use a default @MinDate so you can later check on that value and display a globalized message (in case you are running the SP from .NET)

Comment: That's looks to work well but what is the column so i can call in another expression ? I thought this new column would fit nicely into my "Year" calculation but I can't figure how to call that new column.(YY, AP.Recert_Date, GETDATE())-
  Case
   When DATEADD (YY, DateDiff (YY, AP.Recert_Date, GETDATE()), AP.Recert_Date) > GETDATE () Then 1 
   Else 0
  End

Comment: What i was trying to do is subtract today's date from the "Max Date" but the column name of MaxDate comes back as invalid column name

Comment: SELECT AP.ID, AP.CERT_DATE as 'Cert Date', AP.Recert_Date as 'Recert Date', AP.Recert_Date2 as 'Recert Date 2', AP.Recert_Date3 as 'Recert Date 3',
  (SELECT Max(certification_date) 
   FROM (VALUES (CERT_DATE), (Recert_Date), (Recert_Date2), (Recert_Date3)) AS value(certification_date)) as 'MaxDate', 
   DATEDIFF (YY, MaxDate, GETDATE())-
  Case
   When DATEADD (YY, DateDiff (YY, MaxDate, GETDATE()), MaxDate) > GETDATE () Then 1 
   Else 0
  End
FROM AP

Comment: See my edit again. The problem is that you cannot evaluate the calculated MaxDate field on the same select statement. You should do a nested select like the one on my edit.